# Select2 - only allow one selected AND disabled popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-select2

I'm using the select2 plugin with the property `maximumSelectionSize: 1`. After selecting 1, there is an event still on the form that allows the user to click on the outside of the box and a message will appear to say: "You can only select 1 item".

I don't want this message at all. Is there a way I can ensure that this doesn't ever appear?

EDIT - code posted on request:

```
$('.select2-select').select2({
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
});
```

EDIT 2: aaand a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s85k7tg7/

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: @GeorgeOiko there ya go

Comment: Please add your code in JSFiddle and post the link, so we can see what happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the `select2-opening` event to prevent the drop-down from opening when there is a selected item.

```
$('.select2-select').select2({
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
}).on('select2-opening', function(e) {
    if ($(this).select2('val').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96x965dj/)

Comment: in newer version of selected 2 use 'maximumSelectionLength:1'

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('.select2-select').select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 1
});
```

Comment: $('.select2-select').select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 1
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.select2-select').select2({
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
}).on('select2-opening', function(e) {
    if ($(this).select2('val').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Above code works well with old versions of select2. It only allow users to select at most 1 item and if an item selected, then dropdown won't be shown as customized 'select2-opening' event.

However, with newer versions of select2, this code doesn't work.
Actually 'select2-opening' has changed into 'select2:opening' and the code should be

```
$('.select2-select').select2({
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
}).on('select2:opening', function(e) {
    if ($(this).select2('val').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).